# How to fire a onSelection event from the custom widget to the uibinder

Tags: gwt, widget, custom-component, uibinder, suggestbox

I created a custom SuggestBox using uibinder and I use it in the view that uses uibinder.

My problem is couldnt fire the onSelection event to the view where I am using the custom suggestbox

Below is my code.

**MySuggestBox.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui">
<ui:style>

</ui:style>
<g:SuggestBox ui:field="suggestionBox"></g:SuggestBox>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**MySuggestBox.java**

```
public class MySuggestBox extends Composite implements IsWidget, HasSelectionHandlers<Suggestion>{

    private static mySuggestBoxUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(mySuggestBoxUiBinder.class);

    interface MySuggestBoxUiBinder extends
        UiBinder<Widget, MySuggestBox> {
    }

   @UiField SuggestBox suggestionBox;
   public mySuggestBox(){
       initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
   }

   @Override
   public HandlerRegistration addSelectionHandler(SelectionHandler<Suggestion> handler)  {
      return addHandler(handler, SelectionEvent.getType());
   }
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

and I am using the above widget here

**MySuggestBoxExample.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui
    xmlns:my="urn:import:com.myproject.mywidget">
<ui:style>

</ui:style>
<my:MySuggestBox ui:field="suggestBox" />
</ui:UiBinder>
```

**MySuggestBoxExample.java**

```
public class MySuggestBoxExample extends Composite implements IsWidget{

    private static mySuggestBoxExampleUiBinder uiBinder = GWT
        .create(mySuggestBoxExampleUiBinder.class);

    interface MySuggestBoxExampleUiBinder extends
        UiBinder<Widget, MySuggestBoxExample> {
    }

   @UiField MySuggestBox suggestBox;
   public MySuggestBoxExample (){
       initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
   }

   @UiHandler("suggestBox")
   public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Suggestion> event){
      //I DONT GET THIS EXECUTED
   }
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

I don't get the onSelecion method triggered.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MySuggestBox` doesn't add the SelectionHandler to the actual `SuggestBox`, but to the `Composite` it extends. When the SuggestBox triggers it won't find the handlers added in you suggestion box. You can fix it by adding the handler in your `MySuggestBox` to the actual suggestionbox field:

```
@Override
public HandlerRegistration addSelectionHandler(SelectionHandler<Suggestion> handler)  {
  return suggestionBox.addSelectionHandler(handler);
}
```